# How do I get a macro to run in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, macros, trust

I've written a macro for Outlook and would like it to be run from a button which is visible whenever you compose an email. As such, I've added a button to the Quick Access Toolbar pointing to the macro, given it an icon and renamed it.

I've also gone into the Trust Center (**File > Options > Trust Center > Trust Center Settings.. > Macro Settings**) and changed the security level to "**Notification for all macros**".

I've restarted Outlook yet when I click on the button nothing happens. In Outlook 2003 and Outlook 2007, this would have been enough to get the macro to run.

I've added a breakpoint to the first line of the macro and it is never run. I can only conclude that this means that somewhere Outlook 2010 is still stopping macros from being run.

Does anyone know what else I need to do to encourage Outlook 2010 to run macros?

Comment: where are you writing the code?....is it under ThisOutlookSession??
can you post the code here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out my installation of Outlook was corrupted, which is why macros were not running.

One re-install later and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 7):

You need more info for me to give you a good enough answer, but here's a quick overview of what I did and was successful to get a macro going.

#### If you're looking to have a macro run based on an event:

This means you're looking to have your code run based on events that happen within outlook.  For example, `Application_Startup`.

Under the Developer IDE (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>) select `Microsoft Outlook Objects` -> `ThisOutlookSession`

[image]

Then Select the dropdown that says `General` and Select `Application`.  You'll then be able to select all the event driven methods that you can add.  For Example:

[image]

### If you're looking to just run a Macro

In the IDE, select the toolbars creation button dropdown and select `Module`

[image]

Within the code, create you're module:

```
Sub test()

    MsgBox "Hey Look a Macro!"
    
End Sub
```

You can then run it from the Developer tab:

[image]

*Note: You have to make sure that you enable ALL macros in the security center*

For more information I would highly suggest you read up on the [Developer's website material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814736.aspx).

Comment: Instead of compromising security and enabling all macros, you can self sign your macro by running selfcert.exe, installing the certificate at the trusted root certification - local computer, reopening outlook and chosing always trust this publisher (or if it doesn't pop up on outlook initial load manually press alt-f11 and then choose always trust this publisher).